# application Migrating to weblogic 12.1.3.0 from 10.3.3.0 -unable to render JSF expressions

Tags: jsf-2, struts2, migration, weblogic12c

I am in the process of migrating Struts 2+Jsf 2.x web application from WEB -LOGIC 10.3.3.0 to 12.1.3.0.

I am encountering an error while accessing the pages ,as per my understanding if a JSF tag encounters with a value which is reading from the properties file it is encountering the  Issue.And in the same pages I am able to read the struts messages.

I have created a POC with the same jars which my application is using to check the JSF is rendering properly or not.the POC is working fine.
and I placed the POC created page in to my application and tried to access again the same error encounterd.

when I comment the Struts filter in My application ,newly created pages worked fine.

I have tried to upgrade the Struts2jsf plugin.jar to newer versions .
I have removed the jsf-api,jsf -impl,JSTL from the APPINF\LIB.
changed the faces-config xsd to 2.0

but no luck..

Below is the error stack :

```
java.lang.stackOverflowError.
at java.util.HasMap$treeNode.GetTreeNode(HashMap.java:1873)
at java.util.HasMap.getNode(HashMap.java:573)
at java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
at ognl.ognlRuntime.getParameterTypes(ognlRuntime.java)
at ognl.ognlRuntime.findParameterTypes(ognlRuntime.java)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getGetMethod(ognlRuntime.java)
at ognl.ognlRuntime.hasGetMethod(ognlRuntime.java)
....
at org.apache.struts2.jsf.strutsVariableResolver.resolvervariable(StrutsVaraibaleResolver :78)
at com.sun.faces.el.variabelResolverImpl.resolvervariabel(VariableResolverImpl.java:80))
at org.apache.struts2.jsf.strutsVariableResolver.resolvervariable(StrutsVaraibaleResolver :78)
at com.sun.faces.el.variabelResolverImpl.resolvervariabel(VariableResolverImpl.java:80))
at org.apache.struts2.jsf.strutsVariableResolver.resolvervariable(StrutsVaraibaleResolver :78)
at com.sun.faces.el.variabelResolverImpl.resolvervariabel(VariableResolverImpl.java:80))
at org.apache.struts2.jsf.strutsVariableResolver.resolvervariable(StrutsVaraibaleResolver :78)
at com.sun.faces.el.variabelResolverImpl.resolvervariabel(VariableResolverImpl.java:80))
java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.StackOverflowerror cannot be cast to java.lang.Excetption
java.lang.ClassCastException:java.lang.StackOverflowerror cannot be cast to java.lang.Excetption
at jsp_servlet._error._jspService(_error.java)
at weblogic.servlet.jsp.Jspbase.service(JsPBase.java)
```

**

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <web-app
              version="2.5"
              xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">



    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-Value>classpath:/applicationContext-resources.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext-dao.xml
        classpath:/applicationContext-service.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext-Struts.xml
        /WEB-INF/Secuirty.xml
        </param-Value>
        </context-param>

              <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLE</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
             </context-param>

                    <listener>
                    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
                </listener>

                <servlet>
                   <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name/>
                   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class/>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
                        </servlet>
                <servlet-mapping>
                   <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>
                   <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
                 </servlet-mapping>
        <servlet>

        <servlet-name>JSPSupportServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts2.views.JspSupportServlet</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <filter>
        <filter-name>struts-prepare</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter>
        <filter-name>struts</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphone.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

        <filter>
        <display-name>richfaces</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
        </filter>

        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh </filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD </dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE </dispatcher>
        </filter-mapping>

        <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts </filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

         <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
         <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
         <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
         <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
      </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>sitemesh </filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
 </web-app>
```

faces-config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2"
<application>
           <locale-config>
                <default-locale>en</default-locale>
           </locale-config>
       <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>message</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
       </resource-bundle>
     </application>
```

I have added additionally to the faces config below handler which worked me to display the login page

```
<view-handler>org.ajax4jsf.application.AjaxViewHandler</view-handler>
```

while navigating to any page above error encountering.

Below are the list of jars presented :

```
activation-1.1.jar
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopaliance-1.0.jar
asm3.3.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.6.jar
aspectjweaver-1.6.6.jar
axiom-api-1.2.5.jar
cglib-2.2.jar
commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
commons-Codec-1.5.jar
Commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-el.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
commons-io-1.4.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commong-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.2.jar
commons-vfs-1.0.jar
compass-2.1.3.jar


jsf-facelets 1.1.15B1.jar

richfaces-impl 3.3.jar
richfaces-ui 3.3Final.jar
standard.jar
jstl.jar
jsf-api2.0.2.jar
jsf-impl 2.0.2.jar
log4j-1.2.13 jar
ognl2.7.3.jar
sitemesh-2.4.2.jar
richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar
richfaces-imple-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar
richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar
slf4j-api.jar
slf4j-log4j12.jar
hibernate-core.jar
hibernate-search.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar

standard1.1.2.jar
struts2-corre-2.1.8.jar
struts2-jsf-plugin-2.1.8.1
wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
xml-resolver-1.2.jar
xmlbeans-2.4.0.jar
xmlSchema-core 2.0.jar
xwork-core2.1.6.jar
etc...
```

eg code causing the errors :

```
hello.jsp
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" %>
<head>
        <title>JSF Example</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h2>JSF  Example - </h2>
        <h:form>
           <h:inputText value="#{msg.testmessage}"></h:inputText>

        </h:form>
    <body>
</html>
```

I am struggling a lot what went wrong.and the application is running fine in wls 10.3.3.0.
appreciated your help.

Regards,
Ganesh Karanam